# Returning null or nothing instead of empty array with array.filter

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there a ***vanilla js*** way of returning `null` (or nothing) instead of an empty array`[]`
from `Array.prototype.filter` when no elements are found?
Some *context*:

```
let arr = [1,2,3,1,1]
let itemsFound = arr.filter(e=> e===6)
if(itemsFound){ // always true, []===true
  // do something
}
```

The `if` will always evaluate to `true` as `filter` returns an empty array`[]`.
And an empty array is '**true**' in javascript. Of course I can do,

```
if(itemsFound.length > 0){
  // do something
}
```

But I think just, `if(itemsFound){}` is neater.
The answer would not require additional js libraries.

---

**Additional context**
Coming from an OO background, I found it quite funky that objects and functions
could be treated like Boolean. But felt it was intuitive after getting used to it.
There are times that I would forget that `Array.filter` returns an empty array `[]` when no elements are found. And `[] === true`. This causes unnecessary bugs.

As with the answers and feedback received of now, I don't think this question can be answered except with a new implementation of `Array.filter`.
With that said, the accepted answer is the closest to what I have in mind.

Comment: Are you seriously considering using a JS library just to write `if(itemsFound){}` instead of `if(itemsFound.length > 0)` ??

Comment: I don’t think that really _is_ neater ... With an array, you can still have simple loops over that array anywhere in your code - they would either output something, if the array is not empty, or simply nothing, if it was. If you returned null or false instead, those loops would not work any more, and you had to do a check for whether you have an array or not in each single such place.

Comment: Why is this question voted down, the question asker obviously has some understanding and done some research into what he wants to do. If he had a greater understanding of javascript then he wouldnt be asking the question. This is a very good question to someone who would logically expect filter to return an undefined value rather than an empty array. Please justify why you think this answer should be voted down. I don't think being unsatisfied with filter return a zero length array is a legitimate reason to downvote be honest with you. I have voted this question up

Comment: @MaxCarroll "Why is this question voted down, the question asker obviously has some understanding and done some research into what he wants to do." If **true** research was done, there then OP should understand that empty array is the way Javascript works and has its reasons for this design. Trying to break the design because *Coming from an OO background, I found it quite funky that objects and functions could be treated like Boolean* is not trying to learn nor understand the new technology you're working with.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza, if what you said is true then stack overflow would be empty and there would be no questions because everyone would have just figured it out for themselves

Comment: @MaxCarroll it's different. In fact, there are really interesting questions here. This one, for me, raises from not letting go some concepts and just being stubborn about what OP knew, specially when OP states that *The answer would not require additional js libraries*.

Answer (score 2):

you can do something like this, if you just want to check if it exists or not

```js
let arr = [1,2,3,1,1]
let itemsFound = arr.filter(e=> e===6).length
console.log(itemsFound);
if(itemsFound){ // always true
  // do something
}
```

or something like this

```js
let arr = [1,2,3,1,1]
let itemsFound = arr.filter(e=> e===6)
itemsFound = (itemsFound.length > 0 ? itemsFound : false);
console.log(itemsFound)
if(itemsFound){ // always true
  // do something
}
```

Or something like this

```js
Array.prototype.isEmpty = function(){
    return this.length == 0;
}
let arr = [1,2,3,1,1];
arr.isEmpty();
let itemsFound = arr.filter(e=> e===6)

if(itemsFound.isEmpty()){ // always true
  // do something
  console.log('OK');
}
```

Comment: I'd replace `false` with `null`.

Comment: Your first snippet is closest to what I have in mind.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `length` property of an array and take the value as truthy/falsy value for the condition.

```js
function getValues(array) {
    const result = array.filter(e => e === 6);
    return result.length ? result : null;
}

console.log(getValues([1, 2, 3, 1, 1]));
```